# Android Geolocation accuracy vs smallest displacement

Tags: android, geolocation

The Android GeoLocation API can be configured to manage the power consumed during geolocation and at the same time also provides the smallest displacement setting.

```
 locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(distance);
```

In my application, I was originally using a distance setting of 30m.  Having reduced it down to 10m I have started seeing some strange results - some of the Geo location changes that are reported are quite clearly wrong (typically too small - I thought anything under 10m would simply not be reported?).

setInterval and setFastestInterval are set to 60000 and 15000 respectively.  I should mention that the tests are the outcome of playing around with a Fake GPS provider app - not real world movements.

This has set me thinking... are there general guidelines for geolocation power settings + displacement settings?  In my instance, it looks like BALANCED_POWER is simply not compatible with a displacement setting of 10m.

Comment: what are the values for setInterval & setFastestinterval?

Comment: edited the question to include that information